# Property 'split' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

Hello i have a problem with TypeScript (React). I have 2 components. CountryDetails.tsx component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { CountryProps } from '../interfaces';
import * as ST from '../styles/components';
import { FC } from 'react';
import { InformationCom } from './InformationCom';
import { BorderItem } from './BorderItem';

interface Props {
  country: CountryProps;
}

export const CountryDetails: FC<Props> = ({ country }) => {
  const {
    name,
    population,
    region,
    capital,
    tld,
    currencies,
    languages,
    borders,
  } = country;

  const currenciesList = Object.keys(currencies || {});

  const lang = Object.values(languages || {});

  return (
    <ST.CountrDetailsContainer>
      <h1>{name.common}</h1>
      <ST.CountryInformation>
        <div>
          <InformationCom title="Native Name: " description={name.common} />
          <InformationCom
            title="Population: "
            description={new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE').format(population)}
          />
          <InformationCom title="Region: " description={region} />
          {capital && (
            <InformationCom
              title="Capital: "
              description={capital as unknown as string}
            />
          )}
        </div>
        <div>
          {tld && (
            <InformationCom title="Top Level Domain: " description={tld[0]} />
          )}
          <InformationCom
            title="Currencies: "
            description={currenciesList.join(', ')}
          />
          <InformationCom title="Languages: " description={lang.join(', ')} />
        </div>
      </ST.CountryInformation>
      {borders && <BorderItem border={borders} />}
    </ST.CountrDetailsContainer>
  );
};
```

And BorderItem component:

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
import React from 'react';
import { FC } from 'react';

interface Props {
  border: string | string[];
}

export const BorderItem: FC<Props> = ({ border }) => {
  const [toShow, toSend] = border.split('/');

  return (
    <Link href={`/name/${toSend}`} passHref>
      <li>{toShow}</li>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

In the BorderItem component

```js
const [toShow, toSend] = border.split('/');
```

and Property 'split' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'.
Property 'split' does not exist on type 'string[]'. says. What should I do here? I'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: You cannot use the `split` method on array. And `border` can be either a string or an array

Comment: If `border` is already an array then it won't have a `split` method and this will cause a runtime error. Instead, check to see if it is an array first and split if it isn't. Eg: `const [toShow, toSend] = border instanceof Array ? border : border.split("/")`

Comment: unclear how a string can also be an array of strings.

Comment: If you are not fan of `instanceof` you can also use `Array.isArray(...)`. @epascarello  the property is defined as the following `border: string | string[];` (see above) this is possible in typescript. And ... in javascript and other languages as sting is an "array" of characters with special.

Comment: @ThomasRenger when i apply your solution it works also your solution also  CRice's solution works. Thank you both.